# Array problems with JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to output a JSON feed in PHP and I keep having an issue where the second result in the JSON feed includes the results of the first as well.

Source below, and output:

**Source**

```
function fetch_tour_list($tourID) {
    include('../inc/conn.php');

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM ticket_tour_dates WHERE TourID = $tourID");
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $date['date'] = $result['Date'];
        $venueID = $result['VenueID'];

            $venue_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM ticket_venues WHERE ID = $venueID");
            while($venue_result = mysqli_fetch_array($venue_query)) {
                $venue['id'] = $venue_result['ID'];
                $venue['name'] = $venue_result['Name'];
                $venue['location'] = $venue_result['Location'];
                $venue['latitude'] = $venue_result['Lat'];
                $venue['longitude'] = $venue_result['Long'];

                $venues[] = $venue;
            }


        $date['venue'] = $venues;
        $dates[] = $date;

    }

    echo json_encode($dates);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

**Output**

```
[{"date":"2013-07-29","venue":[{"id":"1","name":"The Gramercy","location":"New York City","latitude":"50.00000000","longitude":"50.00000000"}]},{"date":"2013-08-02","venue":[{"id":"1","name":"The Gramercy","location":"New York City","latitude":"50.00000000","longitude":"50.00000000"},{"id":"2","name":"The Troubadour","location":"Chicago","latitude":"20.00000000","longitude":"25.00000000"}]}]
```

Comment: Don't make queries like that in nested loops. Get all the data in one JOIN query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line before the inner `while` loop:

```
$venues = array();
```